# iOS Push Notification Certificates

Tags: ios, ssl, apple-push-notifications

So the other day I realized the certificate for my app's push notifications had expired. After working with certificates, provisioning profiles, and iTunes connect I have a couple of questions I'm hoping someone might be able to clear up for me:

1. **Is there a way to update push notifications and get it working without having a new build go through Apple's review process?**
   The AppID for the app I have in the App store said that Push Notifications were "configurable" so I went through the process of generating new certificates. After I did that the provisioning profile for the distributed app changed to "Invalid". I'm guessing that to get push notifications working again I'm going to have to build a new version of the app with that new provisioning profile and then have that reviewed by Apple, but I'm really hoping there may be a way to get around that so I don't have to wait [5 days](http://appreviewtimes.com) to get push notifications working again.
2. **When using Apple's Test Flight service, is that considered "production" or "development" and is there any difference to the way push notifications work?**
   I'm trying to get a handle of how this all works so I built a new version of the app with the new provisioning profile and uploaded that to iTunes Connect. I then put the new **production** push notification certificate on my server but that doesn't seem to be working. Am I thinking correctly that apps in Test Flight should use the Production certificate for push notifications?
3. **What is the proper way to generate .pem files from the push notification certificates in keychain access in order to install those on a server?**
   There seems to be a few ways this can be done. I followed [Ray Wenderlich's APN tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/32963/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-2), but this was after following Apple's documentation which suggests exporting the cert and private key together (as opposed to Wenderlich's which has you exporting them separately). I'm wondering if there is a preferred way to do this and if anyone can provide some good documentation or a tutorial on the best way to get the certs onto a server.

---

#### Update

I found [this guide](http://bhaveshkumbhani.blogspot.com/2011/12/convert-p12-to-pem-for-apns.html) on creating the .pem file for a server, its the best guide I've found yet and it seems to be the correct way to do things. Any feedback on the validity of this guide would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a way too much time, I figured out all three of these answers:

1. **YES!** Once I had configured the .pem file correctly for my server, push notifications started working again. No new app build required!**
2. **Production.**
3. **[This guide](https://github.com/grocer/grocer#certificate-file) worked for me.**